# Turn based input from clients using Socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, asynchronous, socket.io

Hi guys I have a small problem here.
I am using Socket.io for a turn based card game. I have an array of player objects, I can access each player's socket and use to send or receive events. I need to go through every player(socket), send them an event to tell them it is their turn, wait for them to take the turn (let's say press a button on the screen) and then on to the next player and so on. I made a couple of attempts but I know that socket.io is asynchronous and basically the loop continues to execute without actually waiting for any players to take turns. Any idea on how I could manage it? To make it more clear of what I am trying to achieve I will demonstrate my last attempts. Thank you!

```
for(i = 0; i < players.length; i++) {
    players[i].getSocket().emit('yourTurn');
    players[i].getSocket().on('turnTaken', function(data) {
        //do something with the data
    }
    //the loop then goes to the next player
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is restructure your logic and UI so that you only notify the player it's their turn when it's their turn, rather than continuously. It'll be their turn once someone else takes their turn (or some other event... game start for instance).

Comment: You mean like have a boolean to indicate if it's the player's turn?

Comment: It doesn't matter how you represent it internally in your node.js app. You just need to know whose turn it's supposed to be. Then notify your all the users about whose turn it is when the game starts or whenever a user makes a turn (for UI modification purposes), and ensure in your node.js app that you only allow turns from the "current user"'s turn.

Answer (score 0):

posting this here just if someone needed it.

I was stuck in the same problem (developing a card game called Tarneeb if you know it, the game involves players taking turns to place there bids, then taking turns to place cards)..managed to solve the problem through the following logic: it pretty much resembles finite state machines if you know it. i created a class called game (server Side) which keeps the game current state and who should make the move, then used events to trigger game moves one by one.

so let's say the code looks like this:

```
function game() //my constructor 
{
    this.gameState = 0 // starting with first state
    this.playerTurn = 0 // starting with first player
    this.gameEvents = new events.EventEmitter() // instantiating event emitter object to deal with game events

    var self = this; // important to access current object from inside event registering functions.
    self.gameEvents.on('init', function(){ 
    // place my init code here then set gameState to be 1 to move to next state 
    // emitting the event move
});
    self.gameEvents.on('move',function(){
    //here i decide which move to take.
    //should update the game object at each client here.
    if(self.gameState == 0)
    {
        // send to clients an event they should do at this state.
    }
    else if(self.gameState == 1)
    {
        //send to clients another (different) event.
    }
    //and so on....
}
```

i then made emitting events do the trick. so for example at state 1 i emit to clients an event that asks them to capture the bids of a certain client. clients manage to resolve the conflict of which client to take the move through checking on variables of the game object (this is another object i keep at each client and update it before each move). and only the client that managed to take it's turn responds to the server with the user input.

so code at client side will be something like this:

```
socket.on('takeTurn', function(){
if(game.gameState == 1 && game.playerTurn == myID){
//promote user for input
//send to server
}
}
```

when server receives this it does it's checks to see whether to move to other state or increment player no turn to give turn to the next player. try to think of it like this: make events trigger in such a way that the code will look as if it is sequential.

hope that i clarified things a little bit.